# Cannot see CAPTCHA when submitting an answer

Tags: discussion, support

When I clicked on <kbd>submit answer</kbd>, I got the page shown below.

The problem is: I can't see any CAPTCHA.
If I click on the link, it redirects me to the "About CAPTCHA" page.

When we click on the "submit" button will it transfer data to another domain?

I  am using Mozilla, latest version, on a Windows machine.

[image: Error Snap]

Comment: This happened to me today too. Can it be because I am using a VPN? I don't know why else they would need to check if I am a human. I am a regular user.

Comment: Edited the question, from the comment under my answer. The user's problem is that _they cannot see the CAPTCHA_.

Comment: The captcha is probably loaded from an off-site resource. Any plugins that block third-party content, such as a javascript blocker?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a normal thing. Stack Overflow gets a lot of traffic, and must protect itself from spam.

The CAPTCHA is an interruption, to verify that you really are a human, and not a script (bot) that is posting spam or nonsense.

I can't see the CAPTCHA in your screenshot, you may need to scroll down to see it. Otherwise click the link (the blue "CAPTCHA") word.

Then take the little test. It'll probably show you a few photos and ask which of them are mountains, or cakes, or something like that. Easy for humans, hard for machines.

Your Stack Overflow answer is not transmitted to another domain.

**Update**:

As user @Gimby points out in their comment, the CAPTCHA itself may be loaded from another domain. If you have adblockers, or are behind a firewall, this may be the reason you don't see the CAPTCHA.
The first could be addressed by (temporarily) stopping the blockers, or use a browser where you don't have the blockers installed.

Comment: that is the problem there is no CAPTCHA (image & text) on click of captcha its redirect to about captcha page...

Comment: @umeshsohaliya Was the issue solved? Please do not accept answers until they have solved the issue.

Comment: yes i havent access of stackexchange.com may captcha is loaded from the main domain or other sub domain thanks for help